# Why in scalar product I can multiply two vectors $\overrightarrow{a}_{1x3} * \overrightarrow{b}_{1x3} $ , whereas in matrices products I couldn't?

Tags: matrices, vectors

If a vector is a matrix of one dimention, Why in scalar product I can multiply  two vectors $\overrightarrow{a}_{1x3} * \overrightarrow{b}_{1x3} $ , whereas in matrices products I'd need $a_{1x3} * b_{3x1} $?

For example : scalar product of two vectors :

$$
\overrightarrow{v}*\overrightarrow{w} = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3 \end{bmatrix}*
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}
\\
=(1*0 )+(2*1)+(3*(-1))
\\ 
\overrightarrow{v}*\overrightarrow{w}=-1
$$

But in matrix product I'd need the transpose of $w$:

$$
v*w^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3 \end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
=(1*0 )+(2*1)+(3*(-1))
\\
v*w^T = -1
$$

So vectors are not matrices of one dimention ?  I'm a little confused.

Comment: The scalar product $\dot$ is usually written differently than matrix multiplication for this sort of reason.

Answer (score 2):

In reality you **transpose** one vector for scalar multiplication. What is loosely written as $u\cdot v$ is in fact $u^Tv$ assuming that both vectors are columns. If the vectors are complex the scalar product requires not only to transpose the vector but also perform its complex conjugation.